# Excluding a library from linking (make, configure)

Tags: makefile, libraries, configure

Let's say I have a library in /usr/lib or in /usr/local/lib and make and configure are able to locate it and behave accordingly.

Now, let's say I have another version of such library, and I'm not willing to install; I want to link an executable against this version; my (little) experience tells me that I could to something like this (for instance in the case of a configure script):

```
./configure \
 CFLAGS="-I/My/Non/Standard/Path/libpng-1.5.12" \
 CXXFLAGS="-I/My/Non/Standard/Path/libpng-1.5.12" \
 LDFLAGS="-L/My/Non/Standard/Path/libpng-1.5.12"
```

I think configure should give priority to the the specified version, but what if it does not find it? Does configure silently assume the standard path to the installed library and continues happily? If this is the case how do I exclude a certain library for being considered for linking?

Answer (score 1):

You can't exclude a library from being linked. You may specify a specific version (despite it is probably ugly, especially if the code is not yours).

The easiest way to give priority to your libs is include then first, you can put in the configure or in the environments vars:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/Path/to/yours/include/files:$C_INCLUDE_PATH
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/Path/to/yours/include/cpp/files:$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Path/to/yours/lib/files:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```